# browser.save_screenshot is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, screenshot

I have a file with links and I need to take screenshots of the pages. But my code doesn't want to save images. Code is running without errors, but output folder is empty.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.set_page_load_timeout(100)    
browser.maximize_window()

file = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()
for url in urls:
    url = url.strip ('\n')
    try:
        browser.get(url)
    except:
        print(url + ' took too long')
   else:
       # where images saved
       browser.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\krupn\Desktop\CreateWord\screenshots' + url + '.png')

browser.quit()
```

Comment: You might have an issue with the way you generate your file path. Can you provide the url output.
Might be good to use os.path.join(directory, url + .png) (Safer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure python isn't running in to a permissions issue for writing to the desktop (run as administrator or put another try except on your screenshot writing attempt and print any exception that may be occurring on write).

Also you may be writing the directory above what you think and creating a file called C:\Users\krupn\Desktop\CreateWord\screenshots[url].png (where [url] is your url variable).

You can join your paths using os.join like so:

```
import os

os.path.join(r'C:\Users\krupn\Desktop\CreateWord\screenshots\', "{}.png".format(url))
```

It would also be wise to sanitize your url string before using it as part of a path, if there are any slashes or illegal characters that could explain why saving the screenshot is not working.

**Thanks to user Corey Goldberg for pointing out that the os.path.join example lacked the necessary r prepending the string so that the backslashes didn't act as escape characters**

Comment: As OP stated there is no error generated. Doing a try/catch to only print the error would provide less information as python will through it anyways with a traceback.

Comment: @NicLaforge fair point if selenium doesn't internally handle errors like potentially invalid filenames. If you're certain it doesn't you're absolutely correct.

Comment: your `os.join` example uses backslashes which are an escape char.  you need to either make the path a raw string, escape the backslashes, or replace them with forward slashes.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it and added credit for your correction.